Web worker inside react component causing race condition
I am trying to create a performant timer component in React.js (for learning purposes) and for that I am using web workers. The logic works as expected the first time when I click "Start" button but some weird race like condition starts appearing in countdown when I stop the counter and start again and then stop, only this time it won't stop and timer speed accelerates!
Live code at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/timer-worker-wfs7e3
Trying to explain the process step by step:



Step
Action
Button State
Timer State
Note




1
Clicks "Start"
Text updates to "Stop". Color to "red"
Active
Timer starts as expected with speed as expected


2
Clicks "Stop"
Text updates to "Start". Color to "blue"
Inactive
Timer resets as expected


3
Clicks "Start"
Text updates to "Stop". Color to "red"
Active
Timer starts as expected with speed as expected


4
Clicks "Stop"
Text updates to "Start". Color to "blue"
Active!
Timer resets to 0 but doesn't stop and starts running slightly faster


5
Clicks "Start"
Text updates to "Stop". Color to "red"
Active!
Timer resets to 0 but doesn't stop and starts running even more faster



And so on. This keeps on happening until I refresh my page.
By the looks of it, seems that that there's some race condition going on ( I maybe wrong) And I am unable to figure out the root cause. Is it bug or simply a failure at logical level?
// /src/workers/timer-worker.ts
const timerWorker = () => {
  let seconds = 0
  let timerId: number | null = null

  const INTERVAL = 100

  function dataFactory(time: number, status: "start" | "stop") {
    return { time, status }
  }

  self.onmessage = (event) => {
    if (event.data === "start") {
      seconds = 0
      timerId = setInterval(() => {
        seconds++
        self.postMessage(dataFactory(seconds, "start"))
      }, INTERVAL)
    }

    if (event.data === "stop") {
      seconds = 0
      self.postMessage(dataFactory(seconds, "stop"))
      clearInterval(timerId as number)
    }
  }
}

export default timerWorker

// /src/workers/web-worker.ts
export default class WebWorker {
    constructor(worker: any) {
        const code = worker.toString();
        const blob = new Blob(['('+code+')()']);
        return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    }
}


// src/components/Timer.tsx
import { FC, useEffect, useRef, useMemo, useState } from "react"
import { Timer as TimerStatus } from "../enums/timer"
import TimerWorker from "../worker/timer-worker"
import WebWorker from "../worker/web-worker"

export interface TimerProps {}

const Timer: FC<TimerProps> = () => {
  const [timerRunning, setTimerRunning] = useState(false)
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0)
  const workerRef = useRef<Worker | null>(null)

  const timer = useMemo(() => {
    const secs = seconds % 60
    const mins = Math.floor(seconds / 60) % 60
    const hrs = Math.floor(seconds / 3600) % 24
    const days = Math.floor(seconds / (3600 * 24))

    return `${days}d ${hrs}h ${mins}m ${secs}s`
  }, [seconds])

  const btnStyle = `btn ${timerRunning ? "btn-danger" : ""}`

  function initTimerWorker() {
    workerRef.current = new WebWorker(TimerWorker)
    workerRef.current.onmessage = (event) => {
      console.log(event.data)
      const { time, status } = event.data
      console.log(time, status)
      setSeconds(time)
    }

    // useEffect cleanup
    return () => workerRef.current?.terminate()
  }

  function clickHandler() {
    setTimerRunning((prev) => {
      const newState = !prev
      workerRef.current?.postMessage(
        newState ? TimerStatus.START : TimerStatus.STOP
      )
      return newState
    })
  }

  useEffect(initTimerWorker, [])

  return (
    <div
      id="Timer"
      className="place-self-center bg-white rounded-md p-4 w-80 text-center border border-solid border-slate-200"
    >
      <div className="text-3xl mb-2 font-bold">{timer}</div>
      <button className={btnStyle} onClick={clickHandler}>
        {timerRunning ? "Stop" : "Start"}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Timer

// /src/enums/timer.ts

export enum Timer {
    START = "start",
    STOP = "stop"
}


Live code at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/timer-worker-wfs7e3

FYI - works fine (i.e. as expected) in Firefox - which is really odd

The one thing that could explain it is if two "start" messages are sent without a "stop" between them - add some logic to check for that

@JaromandaX I was in doubt that the online sandbox of stackblitz is to be blamed. I tried running this locally and still getting the issue.

what about in Firefox?

as the final line in if (event.data === "stop") { add timerId = null ... then, before setInterval add if (timerId) clearInterval(timerId as number - this should prevent the issue - doesn't explain why start is being sent twice though - probably some reactjs oddity that I don't know about since I don't reactjs

It's working fine as expected in Firefox - it's strange

the base logic works fine in Chromium based browsers too - so, it has something to do with reactjs + chromium

@JaromandaX Yes, it's working now. Thanks! Your solution actually leaves no scope of error and now it's running as expected in Chrome. I wonder how firefox was working fine with this faulty logic in the first place?

The logic is not faulty. Your code clearly should only send "Start" if the timer isn't running - I suspect that, for some reason, "start" is sent more than once (the second time it's sent) - what I would do to troubleshoot is to have self.onmessage = (event) => { console.log(event.data) to determine if multiple "start" (and "stop") messages are being sent for a single button click

I do see that in Firefox, 2 stop messages are sent each button click - so, perhaps there is some underlying flaw in your code - as I said, I don't reactjs so subtle nuances of the framework are beyond my knowledge
